# Rebuilding Easton Haven Carbon Wheels

Tags: wheel-building

Had a rough off and many spokes in front and rear wheel are broken or badly damaged, so I'm just going to do a full spoke replacement.  Does anyone either have a set of Easton Haven Carbon 26" that they could pluck the spokes on and give me pitches for drive side and non drive side for both front and rear wheels so I can work my way toward a full rebuild, or even better, knowledge of Easton's build process for these wheels from scratch.  Apparently this involves tensioning the drive side spokes first, then non drive to pull to center, then final truing, but what is the initial tension/pitch that the drive side spokes need to come to?  Thanks for checking out my question, hoping to get these rebuilt before the riding season peters out here in the NE, cheers!

Comment: (1) Do you know the rim is still good? (2) Have you built a wheel before? (3) Plucking isn't exactly a reliable way to get the tensions right. You may want to just email Easton for the data you want.

Comment: (1) Rims are perfect, thankfully, spokes were damaged by bent dearailleur/chain and branch in front, which is what caused the crash. (2) many sets built, including a set of easton Haven 29'ers that I had to switch hubs on, to go from a 135x10 thru rear to a 135QR/142thru interchangeable rear, but since I started with the fully built wheel I had spoke tens and pitches fully built, and then drive side after de-tensioning non-drive, so I was able to reverse engineer Easton's process for a perfect rebuild.  (3) Easton very protective over "proprietary" process, not willing to share, so I came here